# Categorical Variable with more than 50 levels

Tags: dataset, many-categories

I am new to analysis. I would like to know relation between my 2 sets of categorical variables , Both my variables has more than 50 levels. Is it a good approach to create dummy variable and do the logistic regression? Please suggest if there is any better approach.

Comment: You can run a chi-squared test for nominal data to see if the two are associated. Take a look at this [link](http://learntech.uwe.ac.uk/da/Default.aspx?pageid=1440). Logistic regression would allow you to fit a model to predict Y given X or vice versa. The two are achieving different things. From the question I am not sure which is more important for you.

Comment: What are the variables and what are you trying to do?

Comment: With so many levels fat chance they are all independent ... maybe better to use some method searching for anomalous cells in the table, maybe https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~neill/papers/kdd08.pdf  or  http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume6/wong05a/wong05a.pdf  can help?  Or, please give more details ...